# Find vulnerabilities in c# project

Tags: c#, wpf, security

I have to check a system, implemented with the .NET framework (WPF Model-View-Presenter pattern), concerning cyber threats and vulnerabilities.

I have the system on a computer which must be disconnected from the Internet.

May you help me what to search?
Are there software which can scan my code by static code analysis?
Where can I read about the required steps to find vulnerabilities in the project?

Thanks.

Comment: Once disconnected from the internet, the ultimate vulnerability is located between the chair and the keyboard... More seriously: this is too vague to answer proprely. What kind of "vulnerability" are you looking for ? What does this "system" do ?

Comment: Read up on this http://www.microsoft.com/security/sdl/adopt/threatmodeling.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Some tools we used:

- Vega (http://www.subgraph.com/products.html)
- Visual studio Code Analysis (Analyze menu, Run Code Analysis on solution), used to enforce best practices and protect against common risks

VS performs static code analysis. Vega is quite useful to find misconfiguration or risks if the software has an http/https interface.